# Switching frames with tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I've got the following application which consists of a menu bar and a frame. On a button press the content of the frame should be changed.

Here's my code so far:

```
import tkinter as tk


class ImageTool(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nsew")
        container.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

        menu = SideMenu(container,self)
        menu.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky="nsew")


        self.frames = {}

        frame = StartPage(container, self)
        backuppage = BackupPage(container,self)


        self.frames[StartPage] = frame
        self.frames[BackupPage] = backuppage

        frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")


        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        print(self)
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

        
class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        startpage_lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page")
        startpage_lbl.pack(pady=10,padx=10,fill="both")
        
        self.winfo_toplevel().title("Image")

class BackupPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.winfo_toplevel().title(" Backup")
        
class SideMenu(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.btn_backup = tk.Button(self,text="BACKUP", command= controller.show_frame(BackupPage))
        self.btn_restore = tk.Button(self,text="RESTORE")

        self.btn_backup.pack(side = tk.TOP, fill= tk.X, expand = True )
        self.btn_restore.pack(side = tk.TOP, fill= tk.X, expand = True )


app = ImageTool()
app.mainloop()
```

My problem is as follows:
When I try to run the code above, I get an error that

`AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'frames'`

However, if I'm not entirely mistaken, I pass the instance of ImageTool to the class SideMenu as controller which is why the command call to controller.show_frame(BackupPage) should work in theory.

What is my mistake?

Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Comment: Interestling enough, if I wrap the command in a lambda function like:

self.btn_backup = tk.Button(self,text="BACKUP", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(BackupPage))

the application runs but only outputs a dot in the console instead of switching the frame

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out on my own.
There were **multiple** issues:

1. The command has to be wrapped in a lambda expression like this:
   `self.btn_backup = tk.Button(self,text="BACKUP", command= lambda: controller.show_frame(BackupPage))`
2. In order for `frame.tkraise()` in the `show_frame()` method to work, the frame has to be loaded on to the grid first:

> ```
> frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
> backuppage.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
> ```

Comment: As an option, you can use `functools.partial` to pass a function and args without calling it as well. `lambda` works as well but there are a few edge cases where it may yield unexpected results.

Comment: @Axe319 Which edge cases would yield such unexpected results? My goal is to build an application as robust as possible so that's a point of interest for me.

Comment: Consider a case where you have a function `def foo(x): print(x)`. Then you declare a variable `x` with `x = 'hello'`. Assigning a lambda at this point like `bar = lambda: foo(x)` doesn't necessarily mean that `bar()` will print `'hello'`. For instance if afterwards you say `x = 'world'` then `bar()` will now print `'world'`.

Comment: Here is a good read on some common gotchas. https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/ Specifically the section on late binding closures.